# Searching and replacing cent symbol in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sed, centos6

```
OS: CentOS 6.5
Python version: 2.7.5
```

I have a file with the following sample of information. 
I would like to search and replace the cent symbol and replace with $0. infront.

```
Alpha $1.00
Beta  ¢55  <<<< note
Charlie $2.00
Delta  ¢23  <<<< note
```

I want it to look like this:

```
Alpha $1.00
Beta  $0.55  <<<< note
Charlie $2.00
Delta  $0.23  <<<< note
```

So this code in command line (which works) is:

```
sed 's/¢/$0./g' *file name*
```

However using python to code it does not work:

```
import subprocess
hello = subprocess.call('cat datafile ' + '| sed "s/¢/$0./g"',shell=True)
print hello
```

There seems to be an error whenever I try to paste the ¢ symbol.

Slightly closer, when I print the unicode for the cent sign in Python, it comes out below:

```
print(u"\u00A2")
Â¢
```

When I cat my datafile, it actually shows up as the ¢ sign, missing the Â. << not sure if this is any help

I think when I'm trying to sed with the Unicode, the added symbol before the ¢ is not allowing me to search and replace.

Error code when trying unicode:

```
hello = subprocess.call(u"cat datafile | sed 's/\uxA2/$0./g'",shell=True)
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 25-26: truncated \uXXXX escape
```

Fixing the uxA2 to u00A2, i get this:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 7: unknown option to `s'
1
```

Any ideas/thoughts?

Both examples I get the error below:

```
[root@centOS user]# python test2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 3, in <module>
    data = data.decode('utf-8')             # decode immediately to Unicode
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa2 in position 6: invalid start byte

[root@centOS user]# python test1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test1.py", line 11, in <module>
    hello_unicode = hello_utf8.decode('utf-8')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa2 in position 6: invalid start byte
```

This is the cat of the file:

```
[root@centOS user]# cat datafile
alpha ¢79
```

this is the Nano of the datafile:

```
alpha ï¿½79
```

This is the Vim of the datafile:

```
[root@centOS user]# vim fbasdf
alpha Â¢79
~
```

Thanks again for all your help guys

ANSWER!!

The SED output from Rob and Thomas works.
File format was saved as charset=iso-8859-1. I was unable to search the document for utf-8 format character.

Identified file charset:

```
file -bi datafile
text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Used following code to change file:

```
iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf8 datafile > datafile1
```

Comment: It'd also be great if you could show us the error you get.

Comment: If this is solved, don't put SOLVED in the title--this isn't Bugzilla. Instead, choose which answer worked best and click the checkmark outline next to it to set it as the answer. If neither answer worked, add your own answer _as an answer_ and checkmark it instead.

Answer (score 1):

Stealing Thomas's answer and expanding on it:

```
import subprocess

# Keep all strings in unicode as long as you can.
cmd_unicode = u"sed 's/\u00A2/$0./g' < datafile"

# only convert them to encoded byte strings when you send them out
# also note the use of .check_output(), NOT .call()
cmd_utf8 = cmd_unicode.encode('utf-8')
hello_utf8 = subprocess.check_output(cmd_utf8, shell=True)

# Decode any incoming byte string to unicode immediately on receipt
hello_unicode = hello_utf8.decode('utf-8')

# And you have your answer
print hello_unicode
```

The code above demonstrates the use of a "Unicode sandwich": bytes on the outside, Unicode on the inside. See http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html

For this simple example, you could have just as easily done everything in Python:

```
with open('datafile') as datafile:
    data = datafile.read()              # Read in bytes
data = data.decode('utf-8')             # decode immediately to Unicode
data = data.replace(u'\xa2', u'$0.')    # Do all operations in Unicode
print data                              # Implicit encode during output
```

Comment: In both examples, i get this error: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 53, in <module>
    hello_unicode = hello_utf8.decode('utf-8')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 517: invalid start byte

Comment: 1) Line 53? Neither example has a line 53. 2) Simplify the datafile. Try one with only one line of text and see if the error persists. 3) What data is in the data file at offset 517?

Comment: Tried it again with a simplified file. The file has 1 line. please see op for reference

Comment: I found the answer. the issue was in the charset. I have to convert the file from iso-8895-1 to utf-8 then i am able to do the search/replace with sed.

Answer (score 0):

Also, change your string to a unicode string, and replace the cent sign with `\u00A2`.

Here's the fixed code:

```
import subprocess
hello = subprocess.call(u"cat datafile | sed \"s#\u00A2#$0.#g\"",shell=True)
print hello
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, but it doesn't seem to work still.

Comment: Try my new edit, I changed some things. There's no reason this wouldn't work, as Python parses the string literal and replaces the unicode cent sign with an actual cent sign before sending it to the function.

Comment: This is the error i get: 

    hello = subprocess.call(u"cat datafile | sed \"s/\uxA2/$0./g\"",shell=True)
    SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 26-27: truncated \uXXXX escape

Comment: Fixed it, try it now.

Comment: sed: -e expression #1, char 7: unknown option to `s'
1
that is what I get

Comment: It executed successfully, however it did not replace the cent symbol with $0.

Comment: i'm not sure if this makes a difference, but the data is acquired by wget

Comment: It should be replacing everything fine, care to elaborate on what it does? Why don't you try printing out the result of the command and putting it here.